# Show that $g(a) = g(b) = 0,\ \int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx=0 $ implies $f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, if for every continuous function $g$ on $[a, b]$ with $g(a) = g(b) = 0, \int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x) dx = 0$,  Show $f(x) = 0, \forall x \in [a, b]$,

I want to prove by contradiction, and then find a continuous $g$ such that $g(a) = g(b) = 0$ but $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x) dx \neq 0$

Proof: Suppose by contradiction that $f(x) > 0 $ for some $x_0 \in [a, b]$. Since $f$ is continuous, $\exists \delta$ such that $f(x) > 0, \forall x \in [x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta]$. Take $g(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x \in (a, x_0 - \delta) \cup (x_0+\delta, b) \\ 
-(x - x_0 - \delta)(x - x_0 + \delta) & \text{ if } x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta) 
\end{cases}$

Now I want to show that since $g$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, then it is integrable. Thus $\int_{a}^{b} g(x) dx = sup L(g, p)$. However, since the lower sum is $> 0$, it follows that the supremum is also $> 0$. Therefore $\int_{a}^{b} > 0$. A contradiction. However, I do not know how to show that $L(g, p) > 0$

Comment: The negation of $f(x) =0 \forall x$ is not $f(x) \neq 0 \forall x$.

Comment: It should be for $\exists x \in [a, b]$. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You cannot take $g = f$ because it might not be the case that $f(a) = f(b) = 0$.

My hint: Suppose $f(x) > 0$ (say; similar if it were negative) for some $x \in [a, b]$. Then $f$ is positive in a tiny interval around $x$. Let $g$ be a kind of "bump" function that is positive near x but is 0 outside this interval. What can you conclude?

Comment: @Pedro, yes that was what my professor suggested as well. I am having trouble coming up with a "bump" function. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: @Pedro, I came up with a "bump" function. And I edited my original post. However, I am stuck at showing how the lower sum has to be > 0

Comment: It is true in general that a continuous function on a compact interval is Riemann-integrable. What are you trying to do with those lower sums? What you have to show now is that $\int_a^b f(x) g(x) dx > 0$.

Comment: In your riemann integral, use your bump function to show that all the terms in the sum are either zero or positive.  Then use your bump function to show that at least one of the terms is positive.   Once you have a sum of zero and positive terms, with at least one positive term, you have a non-zero integral.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(x)(x-a)(b-x)$
 Then $$\int_a^b f(x)^2 (x-a)(b-x) dx =0 $$
 Note that $$f(x)^2 (x-a)(b-x)\geq 0,\ (x-a)(b-x) > 0\ (x\in
 (a,b))$$

If for some $x\in [a,b]$, $f(x)\neq 0$ then since $f$ is continuous, there exists a closed
  set $x\in [s,t]$ : $$ f(x)^2\geq c > 0\ {\rm on}\ [s,t] \subseteq [a,b]$$

Hence $$ \int_a^b f(x)^2 (x-a)(b-x) dx \geq \int_s^t c (x-a)(b-x) dx
> 0 $$ So contradiction.

Comment: This beats me. Very nice choice of $g(x)$. +1.

Comment: I like solutions that are more clever than my patchwork.

Comment: Could you comment on how you showed that the the above integral is 0? If I understood the question, the integral being 0 is a property that is required.

Comment: It is an assumption of $f$. If $f$ satisfies such assumption, we must show that $f=0$. That is, when $f$ satisfies the assumption, if $f$ is not $0$, we complete the proof by showing a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Elaborating on N. S.'s comment, if $f$ is non zero at some $x_0 \in [a,b]$, then it is non-zero in some region $[x_0- \delta , x_0 + \delta ]$. WLOG take $f > 0$ in this region.

Then find a $g$ s.t. $g(a) = g(b) = 0$ but $g(x) > 0$ $ \forall x \in [x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$ (think of defining $g$ piecewise).

Further, make $g$ non zero only in this region 
(i.e. $g \geq 0$ everywhere, but $g >0$ only in $[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$.

If $ x-\delta < a$ or $ x+ \delta >b$, then we take a smaller value for $\delta$.
The final part is to show the integral is non-zero, but this should not be hard to do (think finding the area or in terms of step functions).

Comment: One pedantic issue in your construction of g, it can't just be "non-zero" only in that region.  For example, if g = -f on [x0 - d, x0 + d], then the integral is zero on [x0 -d, x0 + d], and thus everywhere.

Comment: Very true. I had in the line before stated that $g(x) > 0$, but for clarity I should have made that clear with my use of "Better yet".

Having said that, g = -f doesn't work, as it gets a strictly negative integral, but some function that crosses the x-axis could of course work.

Comment: Oh, you're right.  g=-f doesn't work.  Also, I thought when you wrote "non-zero", you were letting it be implied that it couldn't cross the x-axis from meaning "non-zero everywhere" and intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there exists some $n$ such that $f(n) = a$, $a \neq 0$.  Since $f$ is continuous, let $E$ be the open interval around $n$ where $E \subset [a,b] $.

Let $E1$ be the open interval around $n$ such that $sgn(e) = sgn(n) \forall e\in E1 \subset E$.

Let $E2 \subset E1$.

Let $E2 = (c_2, d_2)$, $E1 = (c_1, d_1)$.

Construct $g$ so that $g(x) = f(x)$ for $x \in E1$, $g(x) = 0$ for $[a,b] \cap E2'$, and $g(x)$ connects the parts continuously on $E1 \cap E2'$.

Once you have that, then it should be trivial.  Your integrand will be all one sign on $E1$ and non-zero, and zero everywhere else, which means your integral will be non-zero.

EDIT:

I'll go ahead and attempt to construct $g(x)$ on $[c_1,c_2]$ and $[d_2, d_1]$ explicitly.

$g(x) = f(x)* |\frac{x-c_1}{c_2-c_1}|$ on $x \in [c_1,c_2]$, and $g(x) = f(x)*|\frac{x-d_1}{d_2-d_1}|$.

Answer (score 0):

Counter example:
$f(x)= const$, $g(x)=sin(x) $, $a=0, b=2 \pi$.

Direct computations shows that 
$\int_{0}^{2\,\pi }f(x) \; \mathrm{sin}\left( x\right) dx =0$.

So you need more constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I'll rename the $x_0$ you defined to $c \in [a, b]$.

Let $p$ be the partition $(x_0 < x_1 < x_2 < x_3) = (a < c - \frac{\delta}{2} < c + \frac{\delta}{2} < b)$.

On the intervals $[x_0, x_1]$ and $[x_2, x_3]$, either $g$ vanishes or both $f$ and $g$ are positive, so
$$
   \inf_{x \in [x_0, x_1]} f(x)g(x) = \inf_{x \in [x_2, x_3]} f(x)g(x) = 0.
$$

On the interval $[x_0 - \frac{\delta}{2}, x_0 + \frac{\delta}{2}]$, both $f$ and $g$ are strictly positive, so
$$
  \inf_{x \in [x_1, x_2]} f(x)g(x) > 0.
$$
Summing over all subintervals gives $$L(fg, p) = \delta \inf_{x \in [x_1, x_2]} f(x)g(x) > 0$$

so necessarily $\sup_p L(fg, p)$ > 0.