# $\int_a^b f(x) g'(x) dx = 0$ implies $f$ is constant

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Given $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, $\forall g$ which is a continuously differentiable function on $[a,b]$, with $g(a)=g(b)=0$, the following equation is satisfied:

$\int_a^b f(x) g'(x) dx = 0$.

I want to show that $f$ is a constant.

This is a question similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221795/show-that-ga-gb-0-int-ab-fxgxdx-0-implies-fx-0), but that question ask $\int_a^b f(x) g(x) dx = 0$.

I have tried taking $g = (x-a)(b-x)$, but since I don't know whether $f(x)$ is differentiable, I cannot take $g = f(x-a)(b-x)$ as in that question.

Thank you.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy It was supposed to be $g(x) = \frac{1}{b-a}\left((b-x)\int_a^xf(x) dx + (x-a)\int_b^xf(x) dx\right)$. Then $g(a)=g(b)=0$ and $g'(x) = f(x) - \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx$. This gives us $\int_a^b f^2(x)dx = \frac{1}{b-a}\left(\int_a^b f(x)dx\right)^2$. Then I think [Cauchy-Schwarz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) can be used to finish it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $I=\int_a^b f(s)ds$.

Let also $$g(x) = \int_a^x \left(f(s) - \frac{I}{b-a}\right)ds.$$
Clearly, $g(a)=g(b)=0$. On top of that $g'(x) = f(x)-\frac{I}{b-a}$.

$$\int_a^b f(x)g'(x)dx = \int_a^bf^2(x)dx-\frac{I^2}{b-a},$$or
$$\int_a^bf^2(x)dx = \frac{1}{b-a}\left(\int_a^bf(x)dx\right)^2.$$
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality this implies that the functions $x\to f(x)$ and $x\to 1$ are linearly dependent, hence $f$ is constant.

Comment: @DanielFischer then we should not forget to mention Bunyakovsky in the name of that inequality. Sadly, people do forget it, even though Bunyakovsky's results precede the results of Schwarz.

Comment: True, but the transliteration of Boun'akovskij is not well-defined, which could count as a mitigating circumstance. That's one problem we don't have with Schwarz when we're using a Latin-based alphabet.