# Need to show that $\int_a ^b f(x)g(x)dx=0 \implies f\equiv 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives

The question below is inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221795/show-that-ga-gb-0-int-ab-fxgxdx-0-implies-fx-0) one.

> Assume $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $\int_a ^b f(x)g(x)dx=0 $ for
>   every  function $g$ possessing continuous derivative such that
>   $g(a)=g(b)=0$. Is it true that $f\equiv 0$ on the interval $[a,b]$?

The hint I was given is to cook up a smooth function with compact support out of $e^{-1/x^2}$. Expanded version of the hint was this: set $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x$ positive and $f(x)=0$ for $x$ non-positive and consider $\int_0^xf(t)f(1-t)dt$.

I have no idea what lies behind this hint (i.e., how could one come up with such an integral) and do not know how to use the hint either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $h(x) = f(x) f(1-x) $ looks a little like an upside-down bathtub: it's 0 for $x \le 0$ and for $x \ge 1$, but nonzero (indeed, positive) for $0 < x < 1$.

For any interval $[p, q]$, the function $h_{p, q} (x) = f(\frac{x-p}{q-p})$ is similar: it's nonzero on the interior of the interval, zero outside it.

If you scale it up by a constant, you can arrange that $\int_p^q h_{p,q}(x) = 1$.

You'd like to show that for any $c$ in $[a, b]$, $f(c) = 0$.

Suppose not .. suppose that $f(c) = A > 0$. Then there's an interval $[p, q]$, containing $c$, indeed, with $a < p < c < q< b$ on which $f(x) \ge A/2$. (Why?)

That tells you that 
$$
\int_a^b f(t) h_{p,q}(t)~dt = \int_p^q f(t) h_{p,q}(t) dt \ge \int_p^q \frac{A}{2} h_{p, q}(t) ~ dt.
$$
What can you say about that last integral? How does this related to the claim about $f$ and "any $g$"?

Comment: We want to show that $f(c)=0$ for any $c$ in $[a,b]$, not in $[0,1]$, right? If so, then assuming $f(c)=A>0$ for $c\in [a,b]$ we have $f(c)=A>0$ on $[\alpha,\beta]\subset [a,b]$ by continuity and the triangle inequality, so $$\int_a^bf(t)h_{\alpha,\beta}(t)dt\ge \int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\frac{A}{2}h_{\alpha,\beta}(t)dt>0$$ since $\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}h_{\alpha,\beta}(t)dt$ is positive on $[\alpha,\beta]$. Thus for the function $g(x)=h_{\alpha,\beta}(x)$, the integral is positive, which is a contradiction. Is that correct?

Comment: Oh, darn. I read the problem as being on $[0, 1]$ rather than $[a, b]$, and then used "a" and "b" for a different thing in my answer. I've edited to make it work for the problem as stated. And your contradiction does indeed look correct, yes.

Comment: Thank you. What for do you need to scale $h_{p,q}$ (i.e., why do you need the integral of this function to be one)? Could I replace $e^{-1/x^2}$ with $e^{-1/x}$?

Comment: I'd like the last integral to be at least $A/2$; for that to happen, I need the integral of the "$h$ part to be $1$. As for replacing with $e^{-1/x}$...I think that's OK. The one I used has the property that it's actually $C^\infty$ (i.e., has continuous derivatives of all orders), but I see that your test-function $g$ is required only to have continuous first derivative, so mine was overkill. I haven't checked that yours DOES have continuous first deriv, though, so you'd have to confirm that.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f(y) \neq 0$ for some $y \in [a,b]$, without loss of generality, $f(y) > 0$. Then for some $\delta > 0$, $f(x) > 0$ for $x \in (y-\delta, y+\delta)$, and assume that $\delta$ is such that this interval is still contained in $[a,b]$ (if not, we are free to make it smaller).

Let $G(x) = \exp\left( \frac{1}{1-x^2} \right)$ for $x \in (-1,1)$ and $G(x)=0$ for $|x| > 1$. Then we make $g(x) = G(\frac{x-y}{\delta})$. Now we have a compactly supported function $g$ whose support is exactly $(y-\delta, y+\delta)$, and $g$ is strictly positive on $(y-\delta, y+\delta)$.

What can we say about $$\int_a^b f(x)g(x) dx = \int_{y-\delta}^{y+\delta} f(x)g(x) dx?$$